# What does "love sprung" mean in this song?

Tags: lyrics

In Rihanna's song "Whos that Chick" there's this sentence:

*The night has got me love sprung.*

What does this mean?

Comment: I notice a couple of people have voted to close this as "opinion based", but that is not appropriate in this case, IMHO.  That reason for closing is intended for when askers actually solicit opinions (instead of facts) from others, but that is clearly not the case here.  There is no reasonable way that somebody who does not know what a phase means would know that there is no objective answer in this case, so it's not the asker's fault and it is still a perfectly valid question (which can still have a perfectly *objective* answer of "nobody knows for sure" or "that's a matter of opinion").

Answer (score 2):

It is not a standard idiom of English.  So your interpretation is as good as mine.

Presumably it is some kind of metaphor. The springs in a clockwork mechanism are wound up when it is ready to go. Similarly she is ready for love.